# Failed to read column data in SQL Server replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm replicating the data from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2 using remote distributor setup. I'm getting the below error whenever I run the snapshot replication for the publication. Could anybody help me in resolving the issue?

> Message: Failed to read column data
>   Stack:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.ThrowNativeBcpOutException(CConnection* pNativeConnectionWrapper)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.BcpOut(String strBcpObjectName, String strBcpObjectOwner, String strBaseBcpObjectName, Boolean fUnicodeConversion, String strDataFile, String strLoadOrderingHint, String strWhereClause, Boolean useTableLockHint, Int32 bcpFileFormatVersion)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.BcpOutThreadProvider.DoWork(WorkItem workItem)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.WorkerThread.NonExceptionBasedAgentThreadProc()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.MainWorkerThread.AgentThreadProc()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.BaseAgentThread.AgentThreadProcWrapper() (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
>
> Message: TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   Stack: (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 10054)
>
> Message: Communication link failure
>   Stack:  (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 10054)
>
> Message: Protocol error in TDS stream
>   Stack:  (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
>
> Message: Protocol error in TDS stream
>   Stack:  (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)

Answer (score 0):

Hence we explicitly specified a parameter in the snapshot agent job step to control the bcp threads.

-maxbcpthreads 4

·

There is no ideal number for this, it completely depends, so we need to test and see which number is most optimal for us.

check this link below:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f44d1732-58ba-45ba-af18-4bb3bd342d56/could-not-read-column-data-error-message-after-giving-a-snapshot-for-transactional-replication?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: I tried from 4 to 16 it works sometimes fails sometimes.Not sure wat to infer from it.